# How many elements are in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ of degree at most 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The elements in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ of degree at most $2$ has the form $ax^2 + bx +c$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Does it mean that the total of elements is $3^3 = 27$ since we have $3$ choices for $a, 3$ choices for $b$, and $3$ choices for $c$?

My groupmates told me that there are $63$ in total. I tried writing out all of the elements but still ended up with only $27$.

Comment: Did you ask your groupmates how they arrived at 63?

Comment: They told me that there are separate cases where $ a = 2, a = 1$, and $a = 0$. But I could not understand because I think all of those cases are already included in the 27 possibilities. We are not even sure who is right and wrong yet.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct and there are 27 elements. I'm not sure how your groupmates reached 63.

Comment: Guess: Maybe groupmates (falsely) thought the elements of $\mathbb Z_3$ were $0,1,2,3$ [not realizing $3=0$]. Then they would get $4^3=64$ and subtract one since the zero poly has undefined degree. [So your answer should also have 1 subtracted and be $26.$]

Comment: Wouldn't the zero polynomial be an integer $0$, which is also in the ring?

Comment: Yes the zero polynomial is in the ring, but in discussing polynomials only nonzero constants are said to have degre zero, whereas the zero polynomial is either said to have no defined degree, or sometimes is said to have degree $-\infty.$ [If the latter is done some extra definitions of how that is handled are made]

Comment: Hmm I guess if you count "degree $-\infty$ as in particular being of degree at most $2$ then no need to subtract $1$ from $27.$ But it all depends on what the text says about degree of zero poly, as to whether to subtract $1$ for that.